# PHP IMAP - Get Message ID in gmail

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I've sent myself an email (from outlook to gmail), and if I click **show original** in gmail I can see the following:

[image: message id]

However when I run the following in PHP:

```
print_r(imap_fetchheader($inbox,$email_number));
```

The message ID is missing:

```
Subject: Test
Thread-Topic: Test
Thread-Index: AQHUppuI1MuEEl1ubE+/5eFPvzB8RQ==
Date: Mon, 7 Jan 2019 15:13:23 +0000
Message-ID: 
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Language: en-GB
```

Does gmail hide this information from PHP IMAP or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're showing it in a web browser, your Message-ID is surrounded by < and >, so it is may be interpreted as a tag. You may need to escape it.

Comment: I’ll check this when back in the office tomorrow. If that’s the answer then I’m such an idiot haha. Thanks.